# How to retrieve data from Jquery POST in Zend Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I am trying to use the data sent cia the following JQuery POST:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:  'POST',
        data : JSON.stringify({
            'email' : 'test@example.com',
            'password' : 'mypassword'
        }),
        url:   'http://example/api/login',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        success: function(data){

            //If the response is successful
            if (data.status)
            {
            } else {
            }

        }
    });
```

In Zendframework / ApiGility I would traditionally do something along these lines to grab the information being sent:

```
    $email = (string) $this->params()->fromPost('email',false);
```

Although this is not working with jQuery

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're posting a JSON string rather than a traditional key -> value POST object. This means ZF2 won't be able to pick out the `email` key because it doesn't know how to parse the request.

You either need to sent the data as a Javascript object:

```
data : {
    email    : 'test@example.com',
    password : 'mypassword'
},
```

Or `json_decode` the request body and get the email from the resulting array e.g. `$array['email']`.

Comment: The JSON is because I am posting to ApiGility which only accepts, json, if I otherwsie I get an invalid content type error. I used json decode for this to get at the stdClass object.

Comment: I see, that's fair enough. The `json_decode` route seems sensible!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get to the data:

```
$request = $this->getRequest()->getContent();

$content =  json_decode($request);
$email = '';
$password = '';

if ($content instanceof \stdClass )
{
     $email = $content->email;
     $password = $content->password;
}
```